# How to solve a PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each()?

Tags: php, list, while-loop, foreach, each

Since moving to PHP 8 the code below gave me the error 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each()...'

```
public function Seek($ArrangementID)
{
    $this->populate();
    $bFound= false;
    reset($this->Arrangementen);
    while (!$bFound && (list($i, $oArrangement) = each ($this->Arrangementen)))
    {
        $bFound= ($oArrangement->ArrangementID== $ArrangementID);
        if ($bFound)
        $this->Current_Elm= $i;
    };
    $this->EOF= !$bFound;
    $this->setFieldValues();
    return($bFound);
}
```

Following some other posts with solutions to this error I changed a part of the while-list-each to:  foreach ($this->Arrangementen as $i => $oArrangement)

```
public function Seek($ArrangementID)
{
    $this->populate();
    $bFound= false;
    reset($this->Arrangementen);
    foreach ($this->Arrangementen as $i => $oArrangement)
    {
        $bFound= ($oArrangement->ArrangementID== $ArrangementID);
        if ($bFound)
        $this->Current_Elm= $i;
    };
    $this->EOF= !$bFound;
    $this->setFieldValues();
    return($bFound);
}
```

However, how to incorporate the first part of the while function: "!$bFound &&" into the loop?

```
while (!$bFound && (list($i, $oArrangement) = each ($this->Arrangementen)))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could break out of the loop when you find your element.

```
public function Seek($ArrangementID)
{
    $this->populate();
    $bFound= false;
    reset($this->Arrangementen);
    foreach ($this->Arrangementen as $i => $oArrangement)
    {
        $bFound= ($oArrangement->ArrangementID== $ArrangementID);
        if ($bFound){
            $this->Current_Elm= $i;
            break; // Leave the loop!
        }
    };
    $this->EOF= !$bFound;
    $this->setFieldValues();
    return($bFound);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Salketer. I am not an expert, however I need to update our website to PHP8.1. I am trying this out in a bunch of files where the each needs to be updated. Will let you know if it works.